# asynchronous for loop no hanging

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, asynchronous

I wrote a synchronous for loop like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, CustomClass> entry : assocs.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  CustomClass value = entry.getValue();
  value.tick(key);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes (rarely) `.tick` hangs. If a single `.tick`, no big deal, it fixes itself after a while and doesn't actually matter at all (it's due to a client with slow internet). But if it delays the rest of them then it's a problem.

So I want each loop body to run without waiting for other ones to finish.

Comment: Remember: unless tick takes quite a long time, threading this will slow you down.  Not trying to discourage you, just saying that threading isn't always the answer and you should be sure to measure the performance of your result (Both before and after).

Comment: Save yourself the stress, use streams.

Comment: @Taslim I've never heard of streams, how would that work?

Comment: @BillK I don't necessarily need to thread it (or do I?), the problem is that sometimes (rarely) `.tick` hangs and causes problems with the app as a whole. If a single `.tick` hangs it's no problem, and it fixes itself after a while, but if it delays the rest of them then it's a problem

Comment: If you want one to start while another is still running then you need a thread.  You need to be aware that all your code in "tick" needs to be thread-safe.  With the parallel stream approach you will fire MANY ticks at once, I don't think that's what you want (guessing from the nature of the word "Tick").

Comment: @BillK idk what the standard use of the word "tick" is, but I have many playable classes in a game and each of those classes needs to run something every x seconds. The for loop I wrote loops through the classes.

Comment: The standard use of "tick" would be something that happened periodically, like every 1/100 of a second (like a screen update or game "step")  In general it would be unhealthy for these to run at the same time.  I guess if each entry in a colleciton were being "advanced by one step" (What I'd call a tick) though, that would be fine to do in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

[Andrew's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49681898/7294647) is almost correct, as it uses a fixed thread pool containing 10 threads; if there are more than 10 elements contained in `assocs`, then the eleventh element might stall, as it would be contending for a thread along with the rest of the elements.  The proper way would be to use an `ExecutorService` with a cached thread pool:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

assocs.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
    service.execute(() -> {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        CustomClass value = entry.getValue();
        value.tick(key);
    );
);
```

Comment: My actual for loop body is larger than the one I put in my question, and I've not seen this `->` notation in Java before. can I put a `{` after the arrow to run all my statements within?

Comment: I see, and yes!  I've edited the answer to show you how it should look.

Comment: @minseong The `->` syntax is a [Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest way of parallelising this would be to use parallel streams:

```
 assocs.entrySet().parallelStream()
     .forEach(e -> e.getValue().tick(e.getKey()));
```

But be aware that this will use the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` to execute your threads, which has one less threads than you've got processors.

If you want to increase the parallelism, you can always run in your own ForkJoinPool

```
new ForkJoinPool(numberOfThreads).submit(() ->
    assocs.entrySet().parallelStream()
        .forEach(e -> e.getValue().tick(e.getKey())));
```

Comment: do I need to use `Final` or anything?

Answer (score 2):

It is honestly less complicated to create an ExecutorService than it is to manually manage your own threads:

```
final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

//create a list of Futures, so you know when each tick is done
final List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Map.Entry<String, CustomClass> entry : assocs.entrySet()) {
  final Future<?> future = exec.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      CustomClass value = entry.getValue();
      value.tick(key);
    }
  });
  futures.add(future);
}

// wait for each future to complete before moving on
for (final Future<?> future : futures) {
  try {
    future.get();
  } catch (Execption e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I'd *strongly* recommend that you time running your code in both a multi-threaded and a single-threaded way. Unless `value.tick` takes a *very* long time, it will probably be quicker to do this in one thread; Java has to do a lot of invisible overhead work whenever multi-threaded code is run in order to make sure that memory isn't accessed in an inconsistent way.

Comment: what packages are `ExecutorService`, `Runnable` and `Future` from?

Comment: They are all core java classes: `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`, `java.lang.Runnable`, `java.util.concurrent.Future`

Comment: do the futures even matter? I don't really care when the ticks are done, or even if they finish at all

Comment: If you truly don't care if the ticks complete, you don't *absolutely have to* wait on `future.get`. However, this opens you up to situations like, "java exited before tick was called", or "there's a bug in tick, and no one is catching the exceptions, so you never find out about it".